# Stored Procedure vs Direct Query in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have an excel file that will select roughly 1100 rows with 5 columns of data. Most columns are 5 digits long and are integers. I am using a macro to connect to a SQL server database and  insert these rows into one maybe two tables. This is all its doing and then it closes the connection. So the user opens an excel file that has the rows, clicks a button and it executes the macro.

My question is, should the query be written in Excel since its simple and merely inserts the data into a few tables. Or is it more efficient calling a stored procedure and passing all of the values in the stored procedure and have it allocate where the values go in the different tables. When I mean efficient, i mean which is the quickest? I know this will probably take a few seconds to complete. I just feel going to a stored procedure is an extra point along the path that the data has to get to before it reaches the tables. Am I wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you plan to pass 1100 rows from Excel into SQL Server?

Comment: Why is Excel part of this equation at all?  Is the user entering the data himself?

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel is part of the equation. Soon the customer will do this portion of their work in SQL. For now, they use Excel. The data is changed ever month and entering it themselves. When it is changed (meaning all of it is changed) , the new data needs to get into SQL. This is why I am using a simple button the user will click on that will get the values and send them to SQL. The question becomes, is it better to go direction into to a SQL table using a query developed in Excel or should the macro call a stored procedure and pass the values there and then go to a  SQL table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some advantages to using stored procedures in SQL Server. One is that SQL Server precompiles and saves the query execution plan, which increases performance. With your current method, SQL Server will generally need to generate the execution plan each time. Stored procedures can also reduce client/server network traffic.

So, even though it may seem like an extra point along the path, it actually can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mark d.'s answer, another reason for using a stored procedure is security.

Your comment says that a customer is entering the data into Excel, so if you are putting direct SQL into your spreadsheet, then there is a risk that someone will open your spreadsheet and find out information about your database. But if you use a stored procedure then there is far less that can be learned.

Either way, make sure that you aren't hardcoding any connection string/account credentials into the spreadsheet.